# Why does ssh disconnect, complaining about a corrupt packet?

Tags: ssh, router, home-networking

I run a cluster of 5 computers and I have used ssh-keygen to allow for keyless entry from my main computer to any of the 5 remote computers. A single router connects my main computer with a network switch, which in turn connects the 5 remote computers to the router.

Lately, I have noticed a lot of my ssh connections terminating with the following error:

```
Received disconnect from 192.xxx.xxx.xxx: 2: Packet corrupt
```

I am using static addressing so that is not the issue. When this problem arises, I usually restart, and most of the time the problem goes away.

Is this a hardware issue (ie. faulty router)? If not, how do I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 2):

While not a solution to your specific problem asked, I hope this may point you in the right direction.

When an application abnormally ends repeatedly, with an unknown or ambiguous error, there are at some additional things to do to get more information on the event, which may help you, or help those helping you determine the source of trouble.

One thing that doesn't require additional instances of trouble is checking system logs to see if the application wrote more detailed information there, about the error, or perhaps discover there was a more encompassing event underway at the time, such as an Ethernet interface problem.

The next source of additional information could come from reviewing the application's documentation to see if it has information on the specific error, or a `debug` or `verbose` mode, which will supply more detailed information on the application's operation, either to the session window, the system log, or a logfile of its own.  In the case of my version of `ssh`, running on Mac OS X, `OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011`, its `man` page has the following paragraph:

> ```
>  -v      Verbose mode.  Causes ssh to print debugging messages about its
>          progress.  This is helpful in debugging connection, authentica-
>          tion, and configuration problems.  Multiple -v options increase
>          the verbosity.  The maximum is 3.
> ```

So, invoking `ssh` with `-v',`-vv`, or`-vvv` will supply additional information on future dropped connections, that may help you, or others, determine what the actual problem may be.